# (Beginner question) Why wont my formatted string work properly?

Tags: python, string, visual-studio-code

I am using the Vs Code software to practice my coding skills. I am trying to have the results come out 'Yes' if both inputs are above 100 (Income) and 70 (Credit Score). It seems to only worry about the range of the Credit Score and not the Income. So regardless of how high or how low the Income is, it gives results based off of the Credit Score input only. Can anyone point out any errors in my code? Also there are no Syntax Errors alerting me about anything wrong. Can anyone figure this out?

P.s I understand I could write the code another way but I am trying to use formatted strings because I think it will be beneficial to use in the long run when I start more complex projects. I am new to coding so I am not sure if formatted strings are really necessary, but I prefer them.

```
customer_income = input("Annual Salary: ")
customer_credit = input("Credit Score?: ")

good_income = customer_income >= "100"
good_credit = customer_credit >= "70"

message = "Yes" if good_income and good_credit else "No"

print(message)
```

I am trying to have the results come out 'Yes' if both inputs are above 100 (Income) and 70 (Credit Score). Results ignore Income input and focuses on Credit Score only. But will also return 'No' if Credit Score is above 99.

Answer (score 2):

Oh I see, you have to convert it to `int` if you use `input`:

```
customer_income = input("Annual Salary: ")
customer_credit = input("Credit Score?: ")

good_income = int(customer_income) >= 100
good_credit = int(customer_credit) >= 70

message = "Yes" if good_income and good_credit else "No"

print(message)
```

> Output with `99` and `70` is `no`, and with `100` and `70` is `yes`

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to compare strings but not integers. It will run but the comparison is based on ASCII order.

```py
while True:
    customer_income = input("Annual Salary: ")
    try:
        good_income = int(customer_income) >= 100
        break
    except ValueError:
        print('Please type a number.')

while True:
    customer_credit = input("Credit Score?: ")
    try:
        good_credit = int(customer_credit) >= 70
        break
    except ValueError:
        print('Please type a number.')

message = "Yes" if good_income and good_credit else "No"

print(message)
```

Comment: Ahhh that makes sense thank you! Also thanks for the extra functions, I'm assuming those will help with dealing with decimal inputs as well.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to compare strings, while what you actually expect is to compare the `int`s represented by these strings.

Therefore, you need to parse these strings **to** an `int` with the `int()` function:

```
customer_income = input("Annual Salary: ")
customer_credit = input("Credit Score?: ")

good_income = int(customer_income) >= "100"
good_credit = int(customer_credit) >= "70"

message = "Yes" if good_income and good_credit else "No"

print(message)
```